# Laravel 5.3 include JS Plugins such as jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm wondering whats the right way to include js plugins into laravel to use them in every file in project....

I first included them in the file `/public/index.php`, worked in general but caused some issues that are not acceptable.. So I'm looking for a better way to do it.

I now tried it in my master template `master.blade.php` that's included in every view.. There I used:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

But it's not working, getting `$` is not defined... Using the CDN doesn't change anything as well, so it doesn't seem to be about the path...

Can anybody help me? Been struggling around for days with this now, testing around different ways, but nothing works....

**Edit**: That's the complete file `master.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Shopping Portal') }}@yield('page')</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Shopping Portal') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                   <!-- some nav items -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')

        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <footer class="text-center">
                &copy; 2016
                <ul>
                    <li class="btn btn-default"><a href="/imprint">Impressum</a></li>
                    <li class="btn btn-default"><a href="/support">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>

                @yield('footer')
            </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit2**: I noticed one thing now: When I'm loading jquery again out of a view (so the view starts with that:

```
@extends('master')

<script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

@section('content')
```

), then it works (at least in that specific view), but I'm wondering why... Am I wrong that if I load jQuery in the master template its included to every tempalte using the master template as well?

Comment: Could it be loading order then?

Comment: Check the network tab on Chrome's dev tools. Does the script get loaded correctly? Are all scripts that use jQuery embedded further down the page, after the jQuery script?

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the `master.blade.php` file :)

Comment: I don't think its the loading order, the scripts get loaded first... jQuery seems to be loading fine, looking in the network tab.. I'll edit my question to represent the `master.blade.php` file

Comment: also see the 2nd edit

Comment: Where is the javascript code in question that you are trying to run? Is it part of app.js?

Comment: @tam nearly every view that includes the master view uses javascript, so I have the `@extends('master')` tag and then most times something like `$().ready(function(){})`

Comment: @tam Okay, you brought me on the right track... My js code that I tried to run always was between the `@extends` and the `@section`, now I use every js code in the section and its works

Answer (score 1):

on layout you can add this
`@yield('scripts')`

and on page.blade.php

```
@section('scripts')
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>

@endsection
```

if you want script to be on all pages add it to layout

directly like this

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```